Unable to Refresh Access Token in NextAuth.js with HttpOnly Refresh Token Stored in Cookie (Next.js + Express)
I'm implementing a secure authentication system using Next.js (with NextAuth.js) and Express.js as the backend. The architecture uses JWT access tokens and HttpOnly cookies for refresh tokens to enhance security and mitigate XSS attacks.
I chose Express.js as the backend because I have multiple frontends, including a Next.js web app and an Android app, that need to share the same authentication logic. Centralizing this in Express allows me to manage user credentials and token generation consistently across platforms.
However, I’m encountering a problem where the HttpOnly refresh token is not accessible when trying to refresh the access token from the jwt callback in NextAuth.js. Since NextAuth.js runs server-side, the HttpOnly cookie (containing the refresh token) is unavailable in that context, making it difficult to securely refresh tokens for the Next.js frontend.
Secure Architecture Overview:

Backend (Express):

Handles user authentication (login, JWT generation, refresh tokens).
Stores credentials (username, password), validates the user, and issues JWT access tokens and refresh tokens.
The refresh token is stored in an HttpOnly cookie, while the access token is stored client-side.


Frontend (Next.js with NextAuth.js):

Uses NextAuth.js to manage authentication and session handling.
Access tokens are stored client-side in the NextAuth.js session and are used for API requests.
Refresh tokens are stored in HttpOnly cookies to secure them from JavaScript access.



The Problem:
The issue arises in the NextAuth.js jwt callback when trying to refresh the access token. Since the refresh token is stored in an HttpOnly cookie, it is inaccessible in the server-side environment where the authorize function and jwt callback are executed.
When the access token expires, the refresh token can't be sent to the backend to get a new access token, leading to the following challenge:
Code Snippet of the Problem:
// If the token has expired, try to refresh it
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include', // Send HttpOnly cookie with the refresh token
});

Since the authorize and jwt functions in NextAuth.js run server-side, the HttpOnly cookie is not sent along with the request.
My Backend (Express.js) Setup:
Here is my Express.js backend setup, which handles login and refresh token management:
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const JWT_SECRET = 'your_jwt_secret';
const REFRESH_SECRET = 'your_refresh_secret';
const accessTokenExpiration = '10m';
const refreshTokenExpiration = '7d';

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3001', // Your Next.js frontend
  credentials: true // Enable cookies to be sent across domains
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Mock user database
const users = [{ username: 'admin', password: 'password123', role: 'admin' }];

// Generate access token
const generateAccessToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign({ username: user.username, role: user.role }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: accessTokenExpiration });
};

// Generate refresh token
const generateRefreshToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign({ username: user.username, role: user.role }, REFRESH_SECRET, { expiresIn: refreshTokenExpiration });
};

// Login route
app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Validate the user
  const user = users.find((u) => u.username === username && u.password === password);
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
  }

  const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
  const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(user);

  // Set the refresh token in an HttpOnly cookie
  res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false, // Set to true if using HTTPS
    sameSite: 'Strict',
  });

  // Send access token and user info to the client
  res.json({ accessToken, user: { username: user.username, role: user.role } });
});

// Refresh token route
app.post('/auth/refresh', (req, res) => {
  const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: 'No refresh token' });
  }

  jwt.verify(refreshToken, REFRESH_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Invalid refresh token' });
    }

    const newAccessToken = generateAccessToken({ username: user.username, role: user.role });
    res.json({ accessToken: newAccessToken });
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

My NextAuth.js Configuration:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ username: credentials?.username, password: credentials?.password }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();
        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt', // Use JWT for session
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
      }

      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const tokenExpiry = token.accessToken ? (jwt.decode(token.accessToken) as any)?.exp : 0;

      if (currentTime < tokenExpiry) {
        return token; // Token is still valid
      }

      // If token expired, refresh it
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include', // Send HttpOnly cookie with refresh token
      });

      const newTokens = await res.json();
      if (res.ok) {
        token.accessToken = newTokens.accessToken;
      }

      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

Problem Summary:

Since HttpOnly cookies are not accessible in server-side NextAuth.js callbacks (e.g., jwt or authorize), the refresh token can't be used to request a new access token.
This leads to a failure when the access token expires, as the refresh token isn't being sent to the backend for token renewal.

What I'm Seeking:

Advice or solutions for handling the refresh token with NextAuth.js while using HttpOnly cookies.
How to efficiently manage token refreshing in a secure way (without exposing the refresh token to client-side JavaScript) and still use NextAuth.js for session management.


I've consulted various resources, including ChatGPT and tutorials, to implement the solution. Most examples I found suggest sending the refresh token in the request's header or body and storing it in localStorage or the session, which exposes it to potential XSS attacks.
To enhance security, I wanted to implement a solution where the refresh token is stored in a HttpOnly cookie, making it inaccessible to JavaScript and reducing the risk of token theft. However, I encountered a problem when trying to refresh the access token using NextAuth.js. Since NextAuth.js's authorize and jwt callbacks run server-side, they can't access the HttpOnly cookie that contains the refresh token, making it impossible to refresh the access token as expected.
I'm looking for a way to securely handle refresh tokens in HttpOnly cookies while maintaining NextAuth.js session management for access tokens.
